# Select 7 days ago JDBC

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, date, jdbc

Im creating a JDBC to a restaurant database program where an user may see the report of the last 7 days profit.

I dont know how to select the last seven days, so the program shows the total profit from seven days ago.

I would like to know how i can achieve this, my code would look something like this:

```
   public static void showSevenDaysAgoSells() {
            double value = 0.0;
            try {       
                System.out.println("----Showing last seven days profit----");
                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT sum(total) FROM sells WHERE date > date_from_7_days_ago");
                java.sql.Date date= new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
                stmt.setObject(1, LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("America/Caracas")).minusWeeks(1));               
                stmt.executeQuery();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                rs.next();
                String sum = rs.getString(1);
                value = Double.parseDouble(sum);
                System.out.println("DAYS" + "\t" +  "TOTAL");
                System.out.println(date+ "\t" + sum);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just use `WHERE date > date_from_7_days_ago`

Comment: it gives me this error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.

Comment: By the way i saw the post you linked here before posting this, it did not work for me

Comment: Update your question and show the actual code which caused this error.

Comment: And on which exact line does the code fail?

Comment: at stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));

Comment: Well of course this would fail, as after your update the prepared statement has no `?` placeholders.  Use `WHERE date = ?` and it should start working again.

Comment: yes it works, but it does not do what i need

Comment: If you are using Java 8 and the latest JDBC drivers you can use `setObject(1, LocalDate.now().minusDays(7))` for setting it and `getObject(1, LocalDate.class)` for retrieving dates. It's better not to rely on `java.util.Date` and it's subclasses when you can avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT sum( total_ ) FROM sells_ WHERE date_ > ? ;"
);
```

…and…

```
stmt.setObject(                            // Use JDBC 4.2 method for passing/fetching java.time types.
    1 ,                                    // Specify which placeholder `?` in PreparedStatement (1, 2, 3, etc.). In this case, `1`. 
    LocalDate.now(                         // Get current date (today) in desired/expected time zone. 
        ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )
    ).minusWeeks( 1 )                      // Go back in time a week (7 days).
)
```

## `?`

You embedded your variable `date_from_7_days_ago` within your SQL string. So it is treated as a string literal rather than as a Java variable’s passed value. Replace that variable name with the question mark `?` placeholder for the [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement( "SELECT sum( total_ ) FROM sells_ WHERE date_ > ? ;" );
```

Tip: Avoid naming your columns and other database identifiers with a reserved words such as `date` and `total`. Various SQL databases in total reserve over a thousand reserved words, so a collision is easier than people realize. The SQL spec explicitly promises to never reserve any word with a trailing underscore. So name all your identifiers `date_`, `total_`, and such to never worry about collisions.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Both the Question and the other Answer use the troublesome old date-time classes that have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and flawed. They are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

The [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

## Time Zone

Both the Question and other Answer ignore the crucial issue of time zone.

A time zone is necessary in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

If your business logic requirements dictate [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) rather than a particular time zone, use the constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

To get seven days ago (a week), let the object do the date-math.

```
LocalDate weekAgo = LocalDate.minusWeeks( 1 );
```

## JDBC

If your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complies with JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly use the java.time types via `PreparedStatement.setObject` and `ResultSet.getObject`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , weekAgo );
```

and retrieve:

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class );
```

At least these two JDBC drivers for Postgres may have been updated for JDBC 4.2 though I have not yet tested them for support of java.time types.

- [The PostgreSQL Global Development Group](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/index.html)
- [pgjdbc-ng](http://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/)

If your JDBC driver does not comply, then fall back to using java.sql. But do so as briefly as possible, converting to/from java.time immediately. To convert, look to new methods added to the old classes. In this case we would have to fall back to using [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) using the `valueOf` and `toLocalDate` methods.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , java.sql.Date.valueOf( weekAgo ) );
```

and retrieve:

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getDate( … ).toLocalDate() ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: it gives me the following error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.time.LocalDate. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.

Answer (score -1):

Do

```
    final long OneDayMillis = 86400000l;
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT sum(total) FROM sells WHERE date > ?");
    java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-OneDayMillis*7l);
    stmt.setDate(1, date);
```

Take into account that the current date of your server might be different from the current date of your client machine, therefore it may be better to use server-side date with a SQL statement like

```
SELECT sum(total) FROM sells WHERE date > current_date - integer '7'
```

without any parameter binding from client side.

Comment: Doing milliseconds calculations like that without `java.util.Calendar` can become a problem around DST changes. I know it's an edge case, but that's why you should use it.